# PyAudio and Decibel change and panning

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio, pydub, decibel

I have a pretty basic pyaudio code that plays a wav file.

```
    open_wave = wave.open("tone_silence/l0r1d0_500.wavc",'rb')

    pyAudio_session = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
        data = open_wave.readframes(frame_count)
        return (data, pyaudio.paContinue)
    pyAudio_stream = pyAudio_session.open(
        format = pyAudio_session.get_format_from_width(open_wave.getsampwidth()),
        channels = open_wave.getnchannels(),
        rate = open_wave.getframerate(),
        output = True,
        stream_callback=callback)

    while pyAudio_stream.is_active():
        time.sleep(0.1)

    pyAudio_stream.stop_stream()
    pyAudio_stream.close()
    print("Stopped")
    pyAudio_session.terminate()
```

I have searched every corner of the internet to find a way such that I can change the Decibel level of the stream and pan the stereo output to a specific channel (left speaker only/right speaker only) as per need. But I could not find any method.

I cannot shift to pydub (which actually has this features) because it does not let me close the stream at any time; it plays the full audio and cannot be closed abruptly.

Answer (score 0):

While `pydub` does not have a direct way to stop `audioSegment` play, According to [this documentation](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/pydub/playback.py), it breaks the audio in to half-second chunks to facilitate keyboard interrupts.

Thus if we take audio and run through a `while loop` within a `try-except` block, we should be able to break the play using "Ctrl + c"

Here is a working sample code that pans audio to left or right channel as per documentation from [here](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/API.markdown) and then uses above logic to stop playing upon "Ctrl + c"

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

song = AudioSegment.from_wav("music.wav")

# pan the sound 15% to the right
panned_right = song.pan(+0.15)

# pan the sound 50% to the left
panned_left = song.pan(-0.50)

#Play panned left audio
while True:
    try:
        play(panned_left)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Stopping playing"
        break
```

We get IDLE session prompt back upon breaking from play loop. You can tailor that your needs.

```
Output:
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Stopping playing
>>>
```

This gives you ease of using built-in panning methods within `pydub` and also a hack to interrupt play-back mid-stream. Hope this help you with your problem.

**EDIT-1**
Above solution may run into problem that while loop will play indefinitely (if you don't break it.). It's may be good for testing only.

Another option is to use `python` `multiprocess` module to spawn a process that plays an audio segment and `terminate` it when not needed. This gives more control during playback.

Here is an example.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def play_audio(seg):
    play(seg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=play_audio, args=(panned_left,))
    p.start()
```

When you need audio to be stopped, simply invoke `p.terminate()` either in IDE  or in program.

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
>>> p.terminate()
>>>
```